# How does args.slice(1) separate the arguments that are passed into PhantomJS and forEach(function(arg, i)... function to work?

Tags: javascript, foreach, phantomjs, slice

Reading a book with following example:

```
var system = require('system'),

args = system.args;

console.log('script name is: ' + args[0]);

if (args.length > 1) {
    var restArgs = args.slice(1);
    restArgs.forEach(function(arg, i) {
        console.log('[' + (i + 1) + '] ' + arg);
    });
} else {
    console.log('No arguments were passed.');
}
phantom.exit();
```

I did search with google about the slice function.
However I am confused why slice(1) here can separate the args.
Searched the web and says there usually 2 args for slice(arg1, optional args2)

how does the slice(1) work here to store in restArgs?
Also how does .forEach(function(arg,i)...) works here?

Comment: Please keep your questions to the point, because we don't need to hear your life story. It distracts from the actual issue and future readers would need to read too much.

Comment: Sorry to distract you a bit but it matters much to me. However, from my background with C#,JAVA and SQL, without much exploration with web technology language, where should I start as a solid ground to learn and build up skills with Javascript vs those extensions like Phantom/NodeJS? or I better open another separate question? I am eager to seek advice related to the background that I came across this level of question I just asked. I feel working with Javascript may be far from wheel for what I want to achieve without help of other famous extension like JQuery. What is usual learning path?

Comment: You won't get answers here about how you should learn JavaScript or any other language. Those would be closed rather fast, because such questions are off-topic and opinion-based. It also doesn't look like there is a site on the Stack Exchange network where that would be appropriate. I would suggest that you find a (small) task that you can be passionate about and just try to do it. You will always get back to Stack Overflow to solve problem that appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Slice

As you stated, here is `slice` syntax:

```
arr.slice([begin[, end]])
```

Because the end argument is optional, a call to `slice(1)` **will simply yield the original args without the first arg.**

## forEach

Here is the `forEach` syntax:

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

**This is basically a for loop for each element in the array.**

If we look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) we will see that the callback function has three arguments:

1. currentValue
2. index
3. array

What your code is doing with `restArgs.forEach(function (arg, i)` is looping over each element of the rest of the arguments and pulling out each element. Within this callback function's body, you are able to reference both the current arg itself (with `arg`), and the current index of that arg (with `i`).

Comment: Thx a lot! However, May I further ask the documentation from MDN for arr.forEach? What does the callback [ ] square bracket [ ] mean in the document of MDN what is the difference with those brackets ()? In my code it is () in that callback function. More importantly, why there is empty before the , thisArg inside [, thisArg] and what does the empty mean before , thisArg. I did read the document and your comment that there are 3 arg but I just cannot map the concept with the real code function(arg, i)  with your hints or MDN spec

Comment: The [] in MDN documentation is how they denote optional arguments. They are not required, but often add additional functionality to the function call.